# Git merge specific file and merge attempt no changes

Tags: git, github, merge, versioning

I set up a project with a Master Branch and then below we have four branches that contain only the code pertaining to the specific feature. I made the mistake though of only creating one 'unity scene' amongst all the branches.

The initial command I ran (while on master branch) was `git merge SomeOtherBranch` received a conflict then I did `git reset --hard` then when I retried the `merge` it was saying `'everything up to date'` so I did `git revert someCommit#` but I'm still getting everything up to date without seeing physical changes within the master folder project.

I found out afterwards that you can do a `git merge --ours <specific file>` to I guess overwrite the 'scene' and just keep the master branch scene?

Comment: What is the exact command you used? That doesn't look like a valid `git merge` command.

Comment: (Btw, please [edit] this information into your post rather than including it in the comments.)